# .NET Client - include max_children property in nested sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

based on documentation and 6.5 release notes, we've new property in sorting by nested, named `max_children`. How to pass this property in .net client?

Here's my sort descriptor:

```
SortDescriptor.Field(x => x.Field(y => y.Variants[0].GrossPrice).Order(SortOrder.Ascending).Nested(n => n.Path(p => p.Variants).Filter(f => filerContainer)))
```

and the sort part of json output

```
"variants.gross_price": {
    "order": "asc",
    "nested": {
        "path": "variants",
        //"max_children": 1,//
        "filter": {
            [...]

        }
    }
}
```

`Max_children` is the property i want to pass in. Currently it isn't there. It seems to me it should look like:

```
SortDescriptor.Field(x => x.Field(y => y.Variants[0].GrossPrice).Order(SortOrder.Ascending).Nested(n => n.Path(p => p.Variants).MaxChildren(1).Filter(f => filerContainer)))
```

but there's an error:

> NestedSortDescriptor doest not contain a definition for MaxChildren.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's because you mostly use `max_children` (with an underscore), but once `MaxChildren` (without an underscore).

Comment: I know the problem, newest nest client release is 6.4, max_children is future of 6.5 so it is reason I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

`max_children` on nested sort will be implemented in the client in the next release. In the meantime, it can be implemented by deriving from `NestedSort`

```cs
public class MyNestedSort : Nest.NestedSort
{
    [PropertyName("max_children")]
    public int? MaxChildren { get; set; }
}
```

and then used

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
    .Sort(so => so
        .Field(f => 
            new SortField
            {
                Field = Infer.Field<MyDocument>(ff => ff.Variants[0].GrossPrice),
                Order = Nest.SortOrder.Ascending,
                Nested = new MyNestedSort
                {
                    Path = Infer.Field<MyDocument>(ff => ff.Variants),
                    MaxChildren = 1,
                    Filter = new MatchAllQuery()
                }
            }
        )
    )
);
```

which yields

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "variants.grossPrice": {
        "nested": {
          "max_children": 1,
          "filter": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "path": "variants"
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```